# How to match unspecified number of digits between negative lookbehind and positive lookahead

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex which matches the digits in the following Japanese strings,

```
4日   
12日
```

while ignoring the following strings completely.

```
3月01日
3月1日
3月31日
```

So far, the closest I have been able to get is by using:

```
(?<!月)([0-9]{1,2})(?=日)
```

but this ends up matching the "1" contained in 3月01日 and 3月31日.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a digit pattern to the lookbehind:

```
(?<![0-9月])([0-9]{1,2})(?=日)
     ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ug1xOY/1)

The `(?<![0-9月])` lookbehind will fail all the matches when the current position is preceded with a digit or `月` and backtracking won't return the partial numbers in the unwanted context.